# Align Relative Portal Camera Position

Tags: unity, position, portals

I've been having a bit of trouble with this small piece of code. To set my relative PortalCam position, I first take the *distance* and *angle* from the Portal and Player Cam. Then apply the *distance* and *rotation* to my OtherPortal to get the PortalCams position.

[Desmos link to all the maths](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8lxvvn7z0d)

```
float newX, newY, newZ;
float d;    // Distance between Portal and PlayerCam
float phi;  // Angle between Portal and PortalCam
            // Angle between Portals
float delta = Quaternion.Angle(portal.rotation, otherPortal.rotation);
d = Mathf.Sqrt( (playerCam.position.x - portal.position.x)^2 +
                (playerCam.position.z - portal.position.z)^2 );
if(playerCam.position.x >= portal.position.x)
    d = -d;
phi = Mathf.Atan( (playerCam.position.z - portal.position.z)
                / (playerCam.position.x - portal.position.x) );

newX = otherPortal.position.x - d*Mathf.Sin(phi - delta);
newY = playerCam.position.y + otherPortal.position.y - portal.position.y;
newZ = otherPortal.position.z + d*Mathf.Cos(phi - delta);
transform.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);
```

My problem is that, while this works perfectly when the portals are at 90degrees to each other. The code seems to fail when the portals are in-line.

Is there a mistake in my math? In my code? How can I best fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself, I'd skip the manual math and use Unity's built-in transformation functions for this.

```cs
const Quaternion FLIP = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0); // (0, 1, 0, 0)

void CrossPortals(Transform subject, Transform entrance, Transform exit) {
    // Map subject position into "entrance portal space" coordinates.
    Vector3 entrancePosition = entrance.InverseTransformPoint(subject.position);

    // Here I assume both portals face "outwards", 
    // so "into" the entrance portal needs to be rotated
    // to map to "out" of the exit portal.
    Vector3 exitPosition = FLIP * entrancePosition;
    
    subject.position = exit.TransformPoint(exitPosition);

    // Order matters here (read from the end, back toward the beginning).
    Quaternion relativeRotation =
            // 3. Apply exit portal's orientation.
            exit.rotation 
            // 2. Account for portals facing opposite directions.
            * FLIP
            // 1. Express orientation in entrance coordinates.
            * Quaternion.Inverse(entrance.rotation);

    subject.rotation = relativeRotation * subject.rotation;
}
```

Comment: sory im still way too new at this, but Unity has a built in Transform.InverseTransfromPoint and Transform.TransformPoint. InverseTransformPoint is basically the "inverse" of TransformPoint, but TransformPoint will be like, "Okay, take this Object and move it relative to this OtherObject." <br>Like moving a Child Object in a Prefab, you can scale & rotate the Prefab and the Child Object within it will be scaled & rotated Relative to the Prefab's "[0,0]".

Comment: Sorry, is that a question? I'm not sure what it is you're asking.

Comment: yes, sorry yes. Just to clarify.  I did a quick look into the API and from my understanding... [insert my word vomit here]. Do I have the right idea of how the code you've provided works?

Comment: TransformPoint/InverseTransformPoint are just math functions, so they do not actually move any objects. They take a point in one coordinate system, and give you the same point expressed in a different coordinate system. TransformPoint takes a point from an object's local coordinate system (like the coordinates of vertices in its mesh, or `localPosition` values of its direct child objects) and maps it into world space. The inverse version does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks so much. So from your code: Im taking "Player" position relativeTo "PortalA" (Player coords 'as if' Portal A is '[0,0]'). Then apply that to my "PortalCam" relative to "PortalB". Setting its World Position relative to a Local Position. (Plus I gotta flip the position so that the camera is behind the portal, but you know, extra details...)

Comment: Something like that. If Portal A and Portal B were both referring to the same transform, and we skipped the 180-degree flip in the middle, then this would be a no-op. We'd just shuffle into the portal's local coordinate frame and then back out, getting the same vector/quaternion we started with, up to rounding errors. Adding the flip means we rotate everything 180 degrees around the portal's up axis. Using the exit portal's transform for the mapping back to world space, instead of the entrance's, applies the difference in position/orientation between the portals.